# Unable to unzip zip file using Ionic via WebClient

Tags: c#, unzip, webclient

I am using `Ionic dll` to unzip the zip file. But it is not working for a file which is downloaded via `WebClient`.

It throws following error:

> - Could not read D:\test.zip as a zip file
> - Could not read block - no data!  (position 0x10000002F)

I am using following code for unzip file

```
if (File.Exists(compressedFilePath))
{
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(compressedFilePath);

    zipFile.ExtractAll(directoryPath,ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
    zipFile.Dispose();
}
```

Please suggest any other option available to download a zip file and unzip it.

Answer (score 0):

This is unusual, but may be because the memorystream and/or position is already set, try this:

```
if (File.Exists(compressedFilePath))
{
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(compressedFilePath);
    zipFile.Flush();
    zipFile.Position = 0;
    zipFile.ExtractAll(directoryPath,ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
    zipFile.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: It throws an error from fist line(Same as I mentioned my question). It does not allow me to initialize ZipFile.

Comment: Is it possible the file download isn't complete, or closed? Have you tried this with a locally created and tested zip file to see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and ZIP file was correct. Validated with: `unzip -t {filename}`

Digging a bit more, I found an inner error: `InnerException = {"  Bad signature (0x08A90992) at position 0x004D4914"}`

Then I uncompresssed it with WinRar and compressed it again assuring ZIP compression in WinRar options and voila! It worked!!!

**Probably my previous ZIP file was not full ZIP file compatible.**